# Why does my code never write to the database?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyserial

I have this code, the object is to read one line of serial and then add it to the database if it is valid. The code that sends the serial is terminated with `\n`. When this code was in two scripts it worked as it should, trying to push it together has somehow messed it up.

Here's the code:

```
#GKPCM Database Test

#outline open database, read serial,write string, repeat
import serial
import sqlite3

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/2', 19200, timeout=0)
print ser.name          # check which port was really used

db = sqlite3.connect('Data/telemetry.gkpcm')
cursor = db.cursor()

InsertQuery ="""INSERT INTO vehicletelemetry (date,time,cyclecount,rpm,speed,odometer,oiltemp,airtemp,fuellevel,enginetemp,ind1,ind2,ind3,ind4,ind5,ind6,ind7,ind8) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"""

tablename="vehicletelemetry"
cursor.execute(""" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = ? """, (tablename, ))
QUERY = cursor.fetchone()
print bool(QUERY[0])    # True if exists
if bool(QUERY[0]) !=1:
    print('not in DB')
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE vehicletelemetry(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date INTEGER,time INTEGER, cyclecount INTEGER, rpm INTEGER, speed INTEGER, odometer INTEGER, oiltemp INTEGER, airtemp INTEGER, fuellevel INTEGER, enginetemp INTEGER, ind1 BOOL, ind2 BOOL, ind3 BOOL, ind4 BOOL, ind5 BOOL, ind6 BOOL, ind7 BOOL, ind8 BOOL)''')
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO vehicletelemetry (date,time,cyclecount,rpm,speed,odometer,oiltemp,airtemp,fuellevel,enginetemp,ind1,ind2,ind3,ind4,ind5,ind6,ind7,ind8) VALUES    (031514,013030,18960,3000,22,192768,210,72,98,210,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)')
    db.commit()
else:
    print('DB Table Exists')

#openfile to read

while(1):
    DataLine = ser.readline()
    Valid = bool(DataLine)
    if Valid == True:
            print(DataLine)
            #Read Database for last record date
            LastEntry = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM vehicletelemetry ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1')
            for Records in LastEntry:
                    LastLogDate = Records[1]
                    LastLogTime = Records[2]
                    LastLogCycles = Records[3]
            DataLine1 = DataLine.strip()
            DataLine2 = DataLine1.split(',')
            print(DataLine2)

            #Check Packet for Correct Length
            if len(DataLine2) != 20:
                print (len(DataLine2))
                print ("Invalid Data Length")
            else:
                #Check Packet DataQualifiers to ensure proper package introduction and termination
                if DataLine2[0] != "7887" and DataLine2[18] != "0420":
                    print ("Invalid Data Qulifier")
                else:
                    #Remove Qualifiers So data can be stored
                    PiP = 1
                    DataLine3 = []
                    for Packet in DataLine2:
                        if PiP >= 1 and PiP <= 18:
                            DataLine3.append(DataLine2[PiP])
                            PiP = PiP + 1
                    #Compare Date Time and Cycle Count to Current Record
                    #print(DataLine3)
                    if int(DataLine2[1]) >= int(LastLogDate):    
                        if int(DataLine2[2]) >= int(LastLogTime):    
                            if int(DataLine2[3]) > int(LastLogCycles):
                                cursor.execute(InsertQuery,DataLine3)
                                db.commit()
                                print(Records,DataLine2[3],LastLogCycles,"Data Valid")

db.close()
```

When I run the code, it gets to checking the data for length, but even if it is the right length to continue down the script the code goes back to ser.readline(). Nothing is ever written to the database.

Comment: Where do you ever break if `Valid` isn't `True` ? (eg: you have nothing (short of an exception occurring) to ever stop the `while(1):` you have...)

Comment: I figured it out... i had the indentation wrong... i hate indentation to control methods in python...

Comment: You may find that using 4-space indentation will make any possible errors more obvious (not to mention just more readable for others in general)

Comment: I dont have to break valid being true. valid just checks that serial data has been read, all of the code that follows it is based on the fact that there is some serial data in the variable....and the while(1) is so that the code repeats forever...  also turns out it wasnt an indentation error. back to square one.

Comment: as far as i can tell it gets as far as line 44 before it reads the next erial input then when i force exit it (ctrl+C) it does the rest to line 53 before shutting down

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  You say it gets to checking the data length but it returns even if the string is the right length.  If it ***is*** the right length, do you still see the print output "`invalid data length`"?  If yes - what length does it report.  If no - do you see the "`Invalid Data Qulifier`" output?  If no - can you verify the 3 if conditions are met i.e. `int(DataLine2[1]) >= int(LastLogDate)`, `int(DataLine2[2]) >= int(LastLogTime)` **and** `int(DataLine2[3]) > int(LastLogCycles)`.  If you can edit that info into the question - that would be great.

Comment: this code started as 3 seperate scripts, i am working on merging them all together / finding a way to write them together, the data fed to the serial is controlled and the same length of packets everytime, the only time i see any terminal output is when it tells me the data is the wrong length becasue i terminate the program feeding the serial line, in which case the program trys to fully process the broken string of packets.

Comment: Right. Your code is supposed to output `DataLine` on every iteration (the line `print(DataLine)`).  So, if you see no output until you terminate, that means you're never entering the `if Valid == True` block => one of two things - `Valid` is `False` always (e.g. `DataLine` is an empty string), or the `readline()` method is blocking - pySerial docs indicate it will wait for either an End of LIne (EOL) character or a timeout.  Is it possible that it isn't seeing either of these?  Has the loop with the `ser.readline()` worked when the scripts were split?

Comment: well when the file was split the code was alot shorter in fact it read thustly:

` import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/7', 19200, timeout=0)
print ser.name          # check which port was really used

ScratchFile = open('Data/Scratch.scr', 'a')

x = 1
while True:
 SData = ser.readline()
 Valid = bool(SData)
 if Valid == True:
  #SData = (SData + "\n")
  ScratchFile.write(SData)
 #print(b)

ser.close()`

then the other file actually parsed the file from the buffer file. so i know the condition atleast when its read line by line from a file are correct.

Comment: I guess you got this sorted - but one very little thing I notice is that in your comment code above - you're talking to serial device on `/dev/pts/7`, whereas the code you originally posted is connecting on `/dev/pts/2`.  Could that be the problem?